# Промтой экзамен. Не думаю, что делаю верно

Tags: текст

Мне нужна программа для просмотра и редактирования текстовых файлов. С контекстным меню и аналогичной панелью инструментов - удалить, вырезать, вставить. У меня есть сегодня и завтра (15.06-16.06.21). Может у кого есть готовый вариант.Думаю это не совсем то, так что прошу помочь.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PDF on Google Drive</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/13wDdmPYjUx4zx0n1BveLrPuLo__zKo3n/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ниче не понял..

Comment: По сути важен только текст. Просто вопросы без попытки ришения не принимает

Comment: Хм, блокнот подойдет?

Comment: Думаю и блокнот подойдет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так?

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const action = event.target.dataset.action;
  if (action) {
    document.execCommand(action);
  }
}, 1);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="p-3 shadow">
  <button class="btn btn-primary js-action" data-action="bold">
    Bold
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary js-action" data-action="delete">
    Delete
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary js-action" data-action="cut">
    Cut
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary js-action" data-action="copy">
    Copy
  </button>
</div>
<div class="m-3 p-3 border rounded bg-white" contenteditable="true">
  <p>
    <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent varius luctus erat eget rutrum.</b> Vivamus tincidunt a eros vel dignissim. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris auctor arcu
    ante, a euismod odio malesuada sed. Vestibulum vehicula et tortor ac ornare. Phasellus scelerisque neque facilisis eros pretium, at auctor ante fringilla. Aliquam ut purus ut massa ullamcorper rutrum. Sed suscipit justo sed orci pellentesque, at lobortis
    sem aliquam. Quisque viverra eros quis eleifend ullamcorper. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent ac posuere libero. <i>Quisque ut dolor ut ipsum lacinia accumsan. Proin vestibulum scelerisque dui, sed venenatis justo volutpat at.</i>    Donec volutpat dictum lorem, vitae mattis nibh vulputate ac. Ut eget nisi sed ligula iaculis dapibus ut non velit. Vestibulum condimentum mauris eget risus faucibus, eget posuere dui placerat.
  </p>
  <p>
    Cras varius, orci sed cursus volutpat, ipsum felis fermentum felis, sit amet pharetra leo mauris commodo dui. Quisque laoreet ut erat at elementum. Mauris vel mauris accumsan nisi vehicula ultrices. Nulla ornare bibendum tempor. Etiam ac erat tellus.
    Morbi placerat metus vel nisi ultrices, a mollis nibh dignissim. Maecenas porttitor sapien iaculis, eleifend libero quis, tincidunt sapien. Nam vitae enim nec odio vehicula lacinia posuere molestie metus. Nam ultricies arcu eu velit laoreet, ut consectetur
    erat blandit. Proin et eros eleifend nunc efficitur vulputate tempus at risus. Phasellus vehicula non enim ut mollis. Vivamus sed elementum neque. Praesent mollis cursus facilisis. Curabitur sed nibh in ligula mollis eleifend. Nullam pretium dictum
    porttitor.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ух ты, не знал, что можно делать жирным\курсивом таким способом.